# How to gain more style control over images in markdown?

Tags: css, github, markdown

I am working within GitHub to create and share a tutorial template.

The idea is to keep the text and the images in the tutorial uniform so I have been trying to look up a way to gain a bit more style control over the images.

For its simplicity, I am trying to do this in markdown, but I am having trouble figuring out to do reference styling. I could use any pointers.

Otherwise, I can do this in HTML, but I am trying to keep things simple in order to train anyone who may be creating new tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start a [gitbook project](https://www.gitbook.com) as a markdown-based Git repository.

They propose multiple style [associated to the image block](https://docs.gitbook.com/content-editing/image#image-block).

Otherwise, you can use a static generator engine like [**Hugo**](https://gohugo.io/) to generate from your Markdown HTML page with the style you want, using one of their [documentation theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/tags/documentation/).
Again, this is based on markdown files, which can be stored in a GitHub-hosted repository.